# Batch search and replace?

Tags: linux

I have a few thousand files that I need to search and replace. Is there a software that can open a directory of files, scan those files and then search and replace? I'm aware that you can script something like this. However, I have no interest and prefer to use something that is already made.

Comment: which OS do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Linux you can pipe the results of a `find` command into `sed` to perform the replace.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/searchpattern/replacepattern/'
```

This will find every file in your current directory and below (`.` is your current directory) and replace instances of `searchpattern` with `replacepattern`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows, you could try to use [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).
There's a tab in its Replace window that scans for files in a folder (you can choose an extension to filter) and do search/replace automatically.

Just note that doing thousands of files can take a very long time. This depends on the  specifications of your computer. Just ensure you have a backup of the files you are going to find and replace in case Notepad ++ crashes and you lose data.

Comment: Strange. I contributed to the second part of the answer and it says Diago did it.

Comment: @Sam: looking at the edits history, I saw you put your contribute right after mine, without blank lines. Diago fixed it. Thanks to everybody who made my answer better, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I often work on Windows and various flavours of Unix, and for replacing text I use [sfk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/files/1-swissfileknife).
For example, to replace "foo" with "bar" in all .txt files in folder `logfiles` and all subdirs, type the following:

```
sfk replace -pattern /foo/bar/ -dir logfiles -file .txt
```

It will do a simulation run. Add the `-yes` switch to actually replace the text.

Comment: Are you associated with this project at all or it's developer?  If so please disclose this per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#promotion) or this might be considered SPAM.

Comment: no, I just use the program often for my daily work.